# Hibernate @ManyToOne references an unknown entity

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa

I am receiving the following Hibernate Exception:

`@OneToOne or @ManyToOne on Matchup.awayTeam references an unknown entity: Team`

The simplified Matchup class looks like this:

```
@Entity public class Matchup implements Serializable 
{
   protected Team awayTeam;

   @ManyToOne 
   @JoinColumn(name="away_team_id")
   public Team getAwayTeam() {
      return awayTeam;
   }
}
```

The simplified Team class looks like this:

```
@Entity
public class Team implements Serializable {
    protected List<Matchup> matchups;

    @OneToMany(mappedBy="awayTeam", targetEntity = Matchup.class,
    fetch=FetchType.EAGER, cascade=CascadeType.ALL)
    public List<Matchup> getMatchups() {
       return matchups;
    }
}
```

Notes:

- Both Matchup and Team have subclasses. I'm not sure if this impacts the situation.
- Both Matchup and Team are listed in my persistence.xml as being
  included.
- If I put @Transient annotations on both getter methods, the error
  disappears.

Can anybody shed light on why this exception is occurring?

Comment: You have a TEAM table, yes?  Were you able to get anything to work before you added the @oneToMany?

Answer (score 84, accepted):

I figured out the problem: I was not adding class Team to the Hibernate `AnnotationConfiguration` object. Thus, Hibernate was not recognizing the class.

Comment: In my case I forgot the @entity Annotation at one class and I got the same error message as you. I only post this info if anybody did the same (stupid) bug as me:-)

Comment: Could you describe how to add class Team to the Hibernate AnnotationConfiguration object?

Comment: I think what he meant is to add the targetEntity in the the @ManyToOne(targetEntity= Team.class)

Comment: Had to inform `LocalSessionFactoryBean` about a new annotated entity class.

Comment: Yes, in my case it was hibernate.cfg.xml file in which I added the newly created relation/table.

Answer (score 25):

Along with entry in hibernate.cfg.xml, you'll need `@Entity` annotation on referenced class.

Comment: embedded failed me

Answer (score 10):

If you are using Spring Boot in combination with hibernate, then actually you may just need to add the package to your `@EntityScan` base package array.

```
@SpringBootApplication(scanBasePackages = {"com.domain.foo.bar.*"})
@EnableJpaRepositories(basePackages ={"com.domain.foo.bar.*"})
@EntityScan(basePackages ={"com.domain.foo.bar.*", "com.domain.another.*"})
public class SpringBootApplication extends SpringBootServletInitializer {
}
```

Comment: Thank you! I only had 
`"com.x.y.z.*"` where I needed `{"com.x.y.z", "com.x.y.z.*"}`

Answer (score 8):

Another solution: Check to ensure that the referenced class is included your `hibernate.cfg.xml` file.

Answer (score 4):

I work in a project using Spring and Hibernate 4 and I found out that we do *not* have a `hibernate.cfg.xml` file. Instead, our beans are listed in the file `applicationContext.xml` which looks a bit like

```
<bean id="sessionFactory"
class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.LocalSessionFactoryBean">
    <property name="dataSource">
        <ref bean="dataSource" />
    </property>
    <property name="annotatedClasses">
        <list>
            <value>com.package.Bean</value>
        </list>
    </property>
</bean>
```

Adding my bean to the list solved the problem. You can find some more information [here](http://www.baeldung.com/hibernate-4-spring).

Answer (score 4):

If you do not use the `hibernate.cfg.xml` you can add targetEntity parameter in `@ManyToOne/@OneToMany` annotation with class describing your entity.

For instance:

```
@ManyToOne(targetEntity = some.package.MyEntity.class)
```

Answer (score 1):

In my case it was `persistence.xml` which listed all entity classes except one...

Answer (score 1):

Add the Entity in **all** **persistence-units** of your persistence.xml

Example

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<persistence version="2.1" xmlns="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/persistence" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/persistence              http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/persistence/persistence_2_1.xsd">
  <persistence-unit name="SystemDataBaseDS" transaction-type="JTA">
    <jta-data-source>java:jboss/datasources/SystemDataBaseDS</jta-data-source>
    <class>package.EntityClass</class>
    ...
  </persistence-unit>
  <persistence-unit name="SystemDataBaseJDBC" transaction-type="RESOURCE_LOCAL">
    <provider>org.hibernate.jpa.HibernatePersistenceProvider</provider>
    <class>package.EntityClass</class>
    ...
  </persistence-unit>
</persistence>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to add the Qualified Name (ClassNAME), just like this:

```
<hibernate-configuration>
    <session-factory name="java:/hibernate/SessionFactory">
                  <mapping class="co.com.paq.ClassNAME" />
        </session-factory>
</hibernate-configuration>
```

In the File:

```
META-INF/hibernate.cfg.xml
```

Answer (score 0):

Add the class in `hibernate.cfg` in proper order. First map the file that is going to be referred by another class

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem and I was struggling with it from last couple of hours. I finally found out that the value in packageToscan property and the actual package name had case mismatch.
The package was in upper case(DAO) and the packageToscan had dao as its value. just wanted to add this in case some one find it help full

Answer (score 0):

In my case I had to look through all classes annotated with `@Configuration`. One of the classes defined an `EntityManagerFactory` bean as follows:

```
@Bean
public LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean entityManagerFactory() {
    LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean em = new LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean();
    em.setDataSource(dataSource());
    em.setPackagesToScan("com.mypackage.entities");
    // omitted
}
```

whereas I put a new entity in the package `com.mypackage.components.user.persistence`.
So I had to update the last line of the `EntityManagerFactory` bean definition to:

```
em.setPackagesToScan("com.mypackage.entities", "com.mypackage.components");
```

Also, it won't hurt to look at the `@EnableJpaRepositories` annotation and check its `basePackages` attribute as well. It might well be the case that your new entity resides outside the packages listed in the attribute's value.

Answer (score 0):

I had this problem cz I didnt add "SomeClass" class with `addAnnotaitedClass(SomeClass.class)` to `SessionFactory factory = new Configuration().configure("hibernate.cfg.xml").`

Answer (score -1):

The `unknown entity` error is not a hibernate annotation problem, but rather that the entity is NOT being recognized. You should check your persistence settings, whether you are using pure JPA, Hibernate or Spring.

> By default, Hibernate is capable of finding the JPA entity classes
> based on the presence of the @Entity annotation, so you don't need to
> declare the entity classes.

With Spring you would have an `@Bean` similar to the following to make sure you don't have unknown entities in your package.

```
@Bean
open fun entityManagerFactory() : 
LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean {
    val em = LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean()
    em.setPackagesToScan("com.package.domain.entity")

    //...
}
```

GL

[Source](https://stackoverflow.com/a/60622264/5279996)