# Java Hibernate mapping exception

Tags: java, hibernate

The scenario is following: I'm implementing a shopping cart, where a Customer can choose products from a product catalog, using Hibernate.

I get this exception, but I have no idea what I am doing wrong.

> Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError,
> Caused by: org.hibernate.AnnotationException: @OneToOne or @ManyToOne on com.OrderManagementMaven.bo.ShoppingcartItem.customer references an unknown entity: com.OrderManagementMaven.bo.Customer
>
> at org.hibernate.cfg.ToOneFkSecondPass.doSecondPass(ToOneFkSecondPass.java:100)
> at org.hibernate.boot.internal.InFlightMetadataCollectorImpl.processEndOfQueue(InFlightMetadataCollectorImpl.java:1823)
> at org.hibernate.boot.internal.InFlightMetadataCollectorImpl.processFkSecondPassesInOrder(InFlightMetadataCollectorImpl.java:1767)
> at org.hibernate.boot.internal.InFlightMetadataCollectorImpl.processSecondPasses(InFlightMetadataCollectorImpl.java:1655)
> at org.hibernate.boot.model.process.spi.MetadataBuildingProcess.complete(MetadataBuildingProcess.java:295)
> at org.hibernate.boot.model.process.spi.MetadataBuildingProcess.build(MetadataBuildingProcess.java:86)
> at org.hibernate.boot.internal.MetadataBuilderImpl.build(MetadataBuilderImpl.java:479)
> at org.hibernate.boot.internal.MetadataBuilderImpl.build(MetadataBuilderImpl.java:85)
> at com.OrderManagementMaven.HibernateUtil.(HibernateUtil.java:15)

This is my code:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "SHOPPINGCART_ITEM")  
public class ShoppingcartItem {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private long itemId;
    
    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name="PRODUCTID")
    private Product product;
    
    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name="CUSTOMERID")
    private Customer customer;
    
    private int amount;
    //...
}
```

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "PRODUCTCATALOG")  
public class Product {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.AUTO)
    private long id;
    private double price;
    private String
    //...
}
```

```
@Entity  
@Table(name = "CUSTOMER")  
public class Customer{
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.AUTO)
    private long id;
    @Column(name="CUSTOMERFIRSTNAME")
    private String firstname;
    @Column(name="CUSTOMERLASTNAME")
    private String lastname;
    //...
}
```

I don't think the error is in the annotations, because I changed them a few times and still got the same exception.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Given the error message, could it be the case that the customer entity is not included in the scanned packages, specified e.g. within an `@EntityScan` annotation?

Comment: I added this annotation right now, but its still the same exception

Comment: Have you tried any of the following answer from here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3983135/hibernate-manytoone-references-an-unknown-entity ?